Second window from a button click on flet
I would like to open a second window from a button click, but I'm encountering the error: "signal only works in the main thread of the main interpreter."
I've utilized a chat example, removing the connection parts and renaming it to 'chatMain'. Then, I've constructed a separate main function for the button and set it as the starting point from my flet application:
import flet as ft

class Message():
    def __init__(self, user_name: str, text: str, message_type: str):
        self.user_name = user_name
        self.text = text
        self.message_type = message_type

class ChatMessage(ft.Row):
    def __init__(self, message: Message):
        super().__init__()
        self.vertical_alignment="start"
        self.controls=[
            ft.CircleAvatar(
                content=ft.Text(self.get_initials(message.user_name)),
                color=ft.colors.WHITE,
                bgcolor=self.get_avatar_color(message.user_name),
            ),
            ft.Column(
                [
                    ft.Text(message.user_name, weight="bold"),
                    ft.Text(message.text, selectable=True),
                    ft.Text("___________________________________________________",selectable=True),
                ],
                tight=True,
                spacing=5,
            ),
        ]

    def get_initials(self, user_name: str):
        if user_name:
            return "User" 
        else:
            return "User"  # or any default value you prefer

    def get_avatar_color(self, user_name: str):
        colors_lookup = [
            ft.colors.AMBER,
            ft.colors.BLUE,
            ft.colors.BROWN,
            ft.colors.CYAN,
            ft.colors.GREEN,
            ft.colors.INDIGO,
            ft.colors.LIME,
            ft.colors.ORANGE,
            ft.colors.PINK,
            ft.colors.PURPLE,
            ft.colors.RED,
            ft.colors.TEAL,
            ft.colors.YELLOW,
        ]
        return colors_lookup[hash(user_name) % len(colors_lookup)]

def chatMain(page: ft.Page):
    page.horizontal_alignment = "stretch"
    page.title = "Chat"
    
    def send_message_click(e):
        if new_message.value != "":
            page.pubsub.send_all(Message(page.session.get("user_name"), new_message.    value, message_type="chat_message"))
            new_message.value = ""
            new_message.focus()
            page.update()

    def on_message(message: Message):
        if message.message_type == "chat_message":
            m = ChatMessage(message)
        elif message.message_type == "login_message":
            m = ft.Text(message.text, italic=True, color=ft.colors.BLACK45, size=12)
        chat.controls.append(m)
        page.update()

    page.pubsub.subscribe(on_message)

    # Chat messages
    chat = ft.ListView(
        expand=True,
        spacing=10,
        auto_scroll=True,
    )

    # A new message entry form
    new_message = ft.TextField(
        hint_text="Write a message...",
        autofocus=True,
        shift_enter=True,
        min_lines=1,
        max_lines=5,
        filled=True,
        expand=True,
        on_submit=send_message_click,
    )

    # Add everything to the page
    page.add(
        ft.Container(
            content=chat,
            border=ft.border.all(1, ft.colors.OUTLINE),
            border_radius=5,
            padding=10,
            expand=True,
        ),
        ft.Row(
            [
                new_message,
                ft.IconButton(
                    icon=ft.icons.SEND_ROUNDED,
                    tooltip="Send message",
                    on_click=send_message_click,
                ),
            ]
        ),
    )


def main(page: ft.Page):
    #page.window_width = 300
    #page.window_height = 300
    page.bgcolor = "transparent"
    page.vertical_alignment = "center"
    page.horizontal_alignment = "center"
    page.window_title_bar_hidden = True
    page.window_frameless = True
    page.window_bgcolor = "transparent"
    page.window_opacity = 100
    page.window_resizable = False
    page.window_focused = True

    def hoverme(e):
    if e.data == 'true':
        e.control.scale = ft.transform.Scale(scale = 1.5)
    else:
        e.control.scale = ft.transform.Scale(scale = 1)
    page.update()

    def oppen_chat(e):
        ft.app(target=chatMain)

    
    page.add(ft.WindowDragArea(
    ft.MenuBar(
    expand=True,
    style=ft.MenuStyle(
        alignment=ft.alignment.top_left,
        bgcolor="blue800",
        mouse_cursor={ft.MaterialState.HOVERED: ft.MouseCursor.WAIT,
                      ft.MaterialState.DEFAULT: ft.MouseCursor.ZOOM_OUT},
    ),
    controls=[
        ft.SubmenuButton(
            ft.ElevatedButton(text="Chat", bgcolor= "blue800", color= "white",
                   on_hover=hoverme, animate_scale = ft.animation.Animation(100, "bounceInOut"),
                     on_click= oppen_chat)

        ),
            ]
        )
    )
)

ft.app(target=main)
import flet as ft

class Message():
    def __init__(self, user_name: str, text: str, message_type: str):
        self.user_name = user_name
        self.text = text
        self.message_type = message_type

class ChatMessage(ft.Row):
    def __init__(self, message: Message):
        super().__init__()
        self.vertical_alignment="start"
        self.controls=[
            ft.CircleAvatar(
                content=ft.Text(self.get_initials(message.user_name)),
                color=ft.colors.WHITE,
                bgcolor=self.get_avatar_color(message.user_name),
            ),
            ft.Column(
                [
                    ft.Text(message.user_name, weight="bold"),
                    ft.Text(message.text, selectable=True),
                    ft.Text("___________________________________________________",selectable=True),
                ],
                tight=True,
                spacing=5,
            ),
        ]

    def get_initials(self, user_name: str):
        if user_name:
            return "User" 
        else:
            return "User"  # or any default value you prefer

    def get_avatar_color(self, user_name: str):
        colors_lookup = [
            ft.colors.AMBER,
            ft.colors.BLUE,
            ft.colors.BROWN,
            ft.colors.CYAN,
            ft.colors.GREEN,
            ft.colors.INDIGO,
            ft.colors.LIME,
            ft.colors.ORANGE,
            ft.colors.PINK,
            ft.colors.PURPLE,
            ft.colors.RED,
            ft.colors.TEAL,
            ft.colors.YELLOW,
        ]
        return colors_lookup[hash(user_name) % len(colors_lookup)]

def chatMain(page: ft.Page):
    page.horizontal_alignment = "stretch"
    page.title = "Chat"
    
    def send_message_click(e):
        if new_message.value != "":
            page.pubsub.send_all(Message(page.session.get("user_name"), new_message.    value, message_type="chat_message"))
            new_message.value = ""
            new_message.focus()
            page.update()

    def on_message(message: Message):
        if message.message_type == "chat_message":
            m = ChatMessage(message)
        elif message.message_type == "login_message":
            m = ft.Text(message.text, italic=True, color=ft.colors.BLACK45, size=12)
        chat.controls.append(m)
        page.update()

    page.pubsub.subscribe(on_message)

    # Chat messages
    chat = ft.ListView(
        expand=True,
        spacing=10,
        auto_scroll=True,
    )

    # A new message entry form
    new_message = ft.TextField(
        hint_text="Write a message...",
        autofocus=True,
        shift_enter=True,
        min_lines=1,
        max_lines=5,
        filled=True,
        expand=True,
        on_submit=send_message_click,
    )

    # Add everything to the page
    page.add(
        ft.Container(
            content=chat,
            border=ft.border.all(1, ft.colors.OUTLINE),
            border_radius=5,
            padding=10,
            expand=True,
        ),
        ft.Row(
            [
                new_message,
                ft.IconButton(
                    icon=ft.icons.SEND_ROUNDED,
                    tooltip="Send message",
                    on_click=send_message_click,
                ),
            ]
        ),
    )


def main(page: ft.Page):
    #page.window_width = 300
    #page.window_height = 300
    page.bgcolor = "transparent"
    page.vertical_alignment = "center"
    page.horizontal_alignment = "center"
    page.window_title_bar_hidden = True
    page.window_frameless = True
    page.window_bgcolor = "transparent"
    page.window_opacity = 100
    page.window_resizable = False
    page.window_focused = True

    def hoverme(e):
    if e.data == 'true':
        e.control.scale = ft.transform.Scale(scale = 1.5)
    else:
        e.control.scale = ft.transform.Scale(scale = 1)
    page.update()

    def oppen_chat(e):
        ft.app(target=chatMain)

    
    page.add(ft.WindowDragArea(
    ft.MenuBar(
    expand=True,
    style=ft.MenuStyle(
        alignment=ft.alignment.top_left,
        bgcolor="blue800",
        mouse_cursor={ft.MaterialState.HOVERED: ft.MouseCursor.WAIT,
                      ft.MaterialState.DEFAULT: ft.MouseCursor.ZOOM_OUT},
    ),
    controls=[
        ft.SubmenuButton(
            ft.ElevatedButton(text="Chat", bgcolor= "blue800", color= "white",
                   on_hover=hoverme, animate_scale = ft.animation.Animation(100, "bounceInOut"),
                     on_click= oppen_chat)

        ),
            ]
        )
    )
)

ft.app(target=main)

